# Customizing Gnome to save screen space

Tags: gnome, menu, titlebar, gnome-shell-extension

After spending many years with Unity (since it's buggy beginnings) I am considering switching to Gnome. Gnome 3.20 looks nice, dash is much more responsive then in Unity...

But, there is one thing that I don't like in Gnome, and that is how much space is wasted on title and menu bar:

[image]

This is especially true in full screen mode. I know Gnome is not Unity, and that you cannot have generic solution for things like integrated menus, but it would be nice to at least be able to hide them on demand.

What I would like to have is extension that:

- removes title bar in full screen mode
- removes menu bar by default and reveals/hides it on `Alt` press for example.

For the first feature, there are [some extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) that aims to solve this, however some of them work only for GTK apps, some of them don't work at all.

For hiding menus, I didn't find any solution.

If you have any tricks/extensions or have ideas how to implement one, I would be happy to participate.

**UPDATE:**

Found interesting extensions for saving screen space:

- [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/), but there is a major [issue](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver/issues/52).
- [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/)

And menus can be hidden in most apps I use Browser, Terminal, Atom editor...

Comment: always come back here to get those extensions name & link =)